# Add custom script in woocommerce refund hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I'm trying to execute a tracking script every time a refund gets processed in woocommerce but for some reason it's not working.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_refunded', 'custom_order_refunded', 10, 2 ); 
function custom_order_refunded( $order_id, $refund_id ) {
if ( $order_id > 0 ) {
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$order_number = $order->get_id();?>
<script>
gtag('event', 'refund', { "transaction_id": <?php echo $order_number;?> });
</script>
<?
}
}
```

I tried executing it with a static value instead of the $order_number variable to see if it was running and nothing... I'm lost

Comment: To start debugging did you check if its working without the `if statement`?

Comment: @kaize I did yes, I'm using a similar script on the thank you page to track the orders and it works fine, I tried removing the if statement on the refund and still doesn't run I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little late to answer this question, but...

You are adding javascript to an action that is only executed in the back-end of PHP and not on a page like the thankyou page.

For Google Analytics to work you need to add your script to a page where the customer can refund their order on the front-end. So for example on their account page.

Here is a nice explanation of creating a refund page in WooCommerce on which you can add your Google Analytics script: https://jilt.com/blog/add-refund-requests-woocommerce-customers/